# SQL Server : return all rows in set if one row has value equal to target value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently working on a SQL query that searches an "archive" database and returns a row for each change that occurred on an order from the beginning of time to today.

What I would like to do with this query is only return the orders that are currently or have been associated with a specific order handler. The best way for me to explain it is that every order is currently grouped in a "set" with a row number for each change, but if one of the rows ever holds the value I'm looking for either "handler" columns, I want it to return all the rows, not just the one with that target value.

Here is what I have so far.

```
SELECT   
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderId ORDER BY EventDateTime) AS RowNumber,
    ace.[OrderId],
    ace.[OrderHandler],
    ace.[EventDateTime],
    ace.[OrderStatus],
    LAG(ace.[OrderHandler], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY [OrderId] ORDER BY ace.[EventDateTime]) AS PreviousOrderHandler,
    LAG(ace.[EventDateTime], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY [OrderId] ORDER BY ace.[EventDateTime]) AS PreviousEventDateTime,
    LAG(ace.[OrderStatus], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY [OrderId] ORDER BY ace.[EventDateTime]) AS PreviousOrderStatus 
FROM 
    Archive AS ace
```

Here is the sample data I receive when running the above query:

[image]

So instead of just returning row number 9 where the OrderHandler = POOL, I want to query if the OrderId has an OrderHandler of POOL at ANY TIME in history, return all the rows.

I figured I could potentially use a `WHERE EXISTS` but I'm not sure how I could return the whole set of results instead of just the results that match.

Any help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: The best way to explain would include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` like this:

```
select a.*
from ace a
where exists (select 1
              from ace a2
              where a2.orderid = a.orderid and
                    a2.orderhandler = @orderhandler
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Script for solution:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ace.OrderId ORDER BY ace.EventDateTime) AS RowNumber
                                          ,ace.[OrderId]
                                          ,ace.[OrderHandler]
                                          ,ace.[EventDateTime]
                                          ,ace.[OrderStatus]
                                          ,LAG(ace.[OrderHandler], 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY ace.[OrderId] ORDER BY ace.[EventDateTime] ) as PreviousOrderHandler
                                          ,LAG(ace.[EventDateTime], 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY ace.[OrderId] ORDER BY ace.[EventDateTime] ) as PreviousEventDateTime 
                                          ,LAG(ace.[OrderId], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ace.[OrderId] ORDER BY ace.[OrderId] ) as PreviousOrderId
                                          ,LAG(ace.[OrderStatus], 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY ace.[OrderId] ORDER BY ace.[EventDateTime] ) as PreviousOrderStatus 
FROM Archive as ace
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderId ORDER BY EventDateTime) AS RowNumber
                                          ,ace.[OrderId]
                                         ,ace.[OrderHandler]
                                          ,ace.[EventDateTime]
                                          ,ace.[OrderStatus]
                             FROM Archive as ace
                             GROUP BY ace.[OrderId]
                                          ,ace.[OrderHandler]
                                          ,ace.[EventDateTime]
                                          ,ace.[OrderStatus]
                                          HAVING ace.OrderHandler LIKE '%POOL%'
                             )x 
                              WHERE ace.OrderId = x.OrderId)
```